# Mime Type for adding sauce labs video link in cucumber report

Tags: selenium, automation, cucumber

I am trying to add a video link to the cucumber report using embedded method in scenario ,
String html = "www.saucelabs.com/asdfs234234sdafs/video.mp4";
scenario.embed(html.getBytes(), "text/html");

In the report i still see as text , not a link , also tried below , now this opening in windows media player instead of in browser
    String html = "https://www.saucelabs.com/asdfs234234sdafs/video.mp4" >VideoLink;
        scenario.embed(html.getBytes(), "text/html");

Can you please help me ? i want a link to appeared in the report by clicking upon , it must navigate to the sauce labs link.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby Implementation: (You can use the same logic in other languages too).
Just call this below line in your hooks.rb, before closing the driver. The below line of code will build the saucelabs video link dynamically based on driver session id.

```
 puts "<button style=\"background-color: #525fa0;font-weight: bold;color: #fff;border: double;border-radius: 25px;\"  onclick= \"window.open('https://saucelabs.com/jobs/#{browser.driver.session_id}','_blank')\">SauceLabs Execution Report</button>"
```

This will add a button to the html report with the saucelabs video link.

If you want to pass the url then use the below code.

```
 puts "<button style=\"background-color: #525fa0;font-weight: bold;color: #fff;border: double;border-radius: 25px;\"  onclick= \"window.open(url_goes_here,'_blank')\">SauceLabs Execution Report</button>"
```

If you are trying to access the html report from jenkins then make sure to run the below line in jenkins console.

```
System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "sandbox allow-scripts allow-popups unsafe-inline; ")
```

Make sure to restart the jenkins, once you ran the script in the script console.
This will allow you to see the report in the html otherwise your url will be blocked.